# Help with a sequence of complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, induction, congruences

I've been trying this for a while and discussed it with some friends but could not solve it. The exercise goes like this:

> Let $(z_n)n\in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence of complex numbers defined by
>
> $ z_1= 6i$
>
> $z_{n+1}= \frac {3(1+i)z_n}{i}$
>
> Prove that:
>
> $ arg (z^2)=
>   \begin{cases}
>     \frac{3\pi}{2}     \quad \text{if } n\equiv 0 \pmod 4\\
>      \pi \quad \text{if }  n\equiv 1 \pmod 4\\
>     \frac{\pi}{2}   \quad \text{if } n\equiv 2 \pmod 4\\ 
>     0      \quad \text{if } n\equiv 3 \pmod 4\\
> \end{cases}$

---

So, first I noticed that an induction would work. I tried to think about it in four different ones, or maybe as different sub-sequences of the original. 
In any case, I found the base cases and computed the first cases to have an idea of what is going on. Basically, my main issue is how to write the inductive step. 
I would write my attempts, but they are just basically isolated notes, drawings and not very clear strategies. I don`t really see how to connect my information with the form of the sequence and my inductive step, which has to do with the argument and the square of the argument. I do notice why this works $\pmod 4$ and what kind of graphic it draws, but that's it.

I think I'd do better with some help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I presume you mean $z_{n+1}$, not $z_n+1$?

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit it.

Comment: I presume you mean $\arg(z_n^2)$ not $\arg(z^2)$.

Comment: Well, what you say makes sense, but that's what the exercise says.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$\frac{3(1+i)}{i}=3(1-i)=3\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi/4}$$

Hence, $\arg(z^2_{n+1})=\arg(z^2_n)-\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $w_n=z_n^2$. Then
$w_1=-36$ and
$$w_{n+1}=\left(\frac{3(1+i)}{i}\right)^2w_n
=\frac{18 i}{-1}w_n=-18i w_n.$$
You should be able to derive a nice general formula for $w_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If we write the sequence as

$$z_{n+1}= \frac {3(1+i)z_n}{i}= 3(1-i)z_n=Az_n,\quad z_0=6i$$

and ignore for the moment that $A$ is complex, then we can readily show by induction that

$$z_n=A^n z_0$$

Then we have

$$
z_n^2=A^{2n}z_0^2\\
\arg (z_n^2)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Im\{(3(1-i))^{2n}z_0^2\}}{\Re\{(3(1-i))^{2n}z_0^2\}} \right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Im\{(1-i)^{2n}z_0^2\}}{\Re(1-i)^{2n}z_0^2\}} \right)
$$

However, my results for the argument differ from yours and repeat in **mod 4** as follows, starting at $n=0$,

$$\arg(z_{n=0...3})=[\pi,~\pi/2,~0,-\pi/2] $$

I have verified both my sequence and argument results numerically. Notice how this solution dovetails with @MarkViola.